# Uniform distribution of points on a cone constrained to a continuous line

Tags: geometry, optimization, uniform-distribution

I was hanging lights on a Christmas tree yesterday, and thought of a problem , which may have an easy solution - but not one that I can think of off the top of my head. It is posed as follows: Consider hanging lights on a Christmas tree. A light strand has a light bulb every $k$ cm, and the Christmas tree is a cone with height $h$ and radius $r$. Is there a way to wrap the lights around the tree such that the lights have a uniform distribution on the surface area of the cone.

More precisely, is there a method which works for all cones, by which one can draw a continuous line on the surface of a cone in such a way that points every $k$ apart on the line form a uniform distribution on the surface of the cone.

Is there a simple solution? Or is it much more complicated than it seems?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the lights have a uniform distribution"?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a limited length that you want to warp around from top to bottom so nothing will be hanging...

Comment: The points on the light strand (which constitute the lights) should form a uniform distribution over the surface area of the tree (the cone) - basically the idea is to avoid clumps of lights. while wrapping the tree. We can assume infinite length.

Comment: "Uniform distribution" has a specific meaning in probability theory which is not what you mean, you just mean that the lights are evenly arranged in an informal sense. I believe this article solves your problem: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/